# Logrotate on Busybox

Tags: busybox, logrotate

I'm using "BusyBox v1.23.2 (2016-05-10 18:40:19 CST) multi-call binary."

How do I achieve logrotate functionality on a particular log file?

Comment: I ended up using cron with a bash script